# In android how to search that sharedpreference contains some value or not?

Tags: android

**In android how to search that sharedpreference contains some value or not?**

Actually I m making application which takes password and confirm password as fields.when user start app for first time he must enter both password and confirm password. But i want  when user restart that app he must ask to enter only password.

**For that i store password in sharedPreferences but now how do i know that  their is already password exists in sharedPreferences or not?**

so that if their is no password in sharedPreferences i can show the activity which contains both password and confirm password  to  enter AND if there exists password then i wl show activity that contains only password to enter.

If Anyone have idea then please help me.I m tring from many days but still not getting the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for saving data...

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("YourKey", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("password", passwordValue);        
     // Don't forget to commit your edits!!!
    editor.commit();
```

for retrieving...

```
 SharedPreferences settings =this.getSharedPreferences("YourKey", 0);
    String userData = settings.getString("password", "0");

    if((userData.equals("0"))){
        //password has not been saved...
    }
    else{
           //password is already there...
    }
```

Comment: I alredy done this but when i run it,it runs only "if" condition part  again and again.why this is happen i can't understand.please tell me & thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can check it by using the `contains` method on your `SharedPreferences` instance:

```
boolean hasPassword = preference.contains("passwordKey");
```

**API Docs:**

```
public abstract boolean contains (String key)
```

Since: API Level 1 
Checks whether the preferences contains a preference.

**Parameters**
`key`  The name of the preference to check.

**Returns**
Returns true if the preference exists in the preferences, otherwise false.

Comment: I alredy done the same code as Umesh post here but when i run it,it runs only "if" condition part  again and again.why this is happen i can't understand.please tell me & thanks

Comment: It must be because you didn't save anything to that preference with the key `"password"`. Are you using the right shared preference? You should take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE). If you want a single person to be able to log in from a phone at a time, then you may use preference = `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());`

Answer (score 0):

fist check if passwort is set:

```
boolean password_exists = !settings.getString("password","").equals("");
```

then hide or show the field for the second password

```
second_passwort_edittext.setVisibility(password_exists ? View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);
```

After entering the password you can change the behaviour with password_exists (compare the passwords and set them if false, compare with given stored password if true)

Comment: I alredy done the same code as Umesh post here but when i run it,it runs only "if" condition part  again and again.why this is happen i can't understand.please tell me & thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could just validate if you have received something by getting the password value from your shared preferences

```
if(preferences.getInt("storedPass", 0) != null) {
    //Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: I alredy done the same code as Umesh post here but when i run it,it runs only "if" condition part  again and again.why this is happen i can't understand.please tell me & thanks